# Maintain fragment reference or find by tag when using FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments

Before the `ViewPager` change the current fragment to the next or previous one, a validation must be done by calling a **custom** `Fragment`s method. To accomplish that, I can either maintain a reference for each fragment, or find them by tag. Here's the code:

```
//=== Inside Activity ===//
Fragment fragments[] = new Fragment[5]

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // .. init code

    fragments[0] = new FragmentA();
    fragments[1] = new FragmentB();
    // ... same for 5 fragments in this particular case
}

private void validateFragmentBeforeMovingToNextOrPrevious(int position) {
    ((MyValidationFragment)fragments[position]).validate();
}

//=== inside FragmentPagerAdapter ===//
@Override
public Fragment getItem(position) {
    return fragments[position];
}
```

Versus

```
//=== inside Activity ===//
private void validateFragmentBeforeMovingToNextOrPrevious(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(
                "android:switcher:" + viewPager.getId() + ":" +
                fragmentPagerAdapter.getItemId(position));

    ((MyValidationFragment)fragment).validate();
}

//=== inside FragmentPagerAdapter ===//
@Override
public Fragment getItem(position) {
    switch(position) {
       case 0: return new FragmentA();
       case 1: return new FragmentB();
       // ... etc...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn’t spot an actual question, so I’m going to assume you’re trying to get feedback on which approach to take. I personally like neither, so this is what I’d do:

```
interface Validator {
  void validate();
}

class MyValidationFragment extends Fragment implements Validator {
  // Implementation follows.
}

class MyPager extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

  private final SparseArray<Validator> mValidators = new SparseArray<Validator>();

  @Override
  public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    final MyValidationFragment fragment = getFragmentSomehow();
    mValidators.put(position, fragment);
    return fragment;
  }

  @Override
  public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    mValidators.remove(position); 
    super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
  }

  private void validateFragment(int position) {
    mValidators.get(position).validate();
  }

}
```

But I understand that this might not be what you're looking for, as it's just another approach to consider.

Comment: quick question, why `SparseArray` and not `ArrayList`?

Comment: Hi @Christoper, sorry for responding late. `SparseArray`, unlike a normal array, can have gaps in the indices. Think of it as a lightweight `Map<Integer, ?>`. `ViewPager` likes to destroy fragments that are not adjacent to the primary `Fragment`. I use it because I don’t want to fiddle with position indices. You could very well use an `ArrayList`, but the implementation might not be as nice and compact.

Comment: I just found an issue with the implementation, I believe `mValidator` is being emptied when a rotation occurs

Comment: Well, it’s not an implementation issue but rather a way the [system works](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html). When you rotate the device, `Activities` and some `Fragments` are destroyed and rebuild, using the appropriate resources. If you wish to preserve the `mValidators` content, you’ll have to find a way to store it in a `Bundle` provided by the e.g. `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)` method. It shouldn’t be difficult.

Comment: can't save a `Fragment` itself on a `Bundle` (which is the content of `mValidator`) but I found that overriding `instantiateItem` and fill the list there rather than on `getItem()` solves it

Comment: To save a `Fragment` to a `Bundle`, call `fragmentManager.putFragment(bundle, "key", fragment);`. Glad you solved your problem.